# Don't understand why the Background property is ignored using a ModernButton

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

I've created a new WPF app using the ModernUI WPF Application template, because I wanted to see how I could style the contents and apparence of the ModernButton. The very first thing I did was try to use the color we've settled on (kind of an off purple). It was completely ignored. OK, why was it ignored? Here's the XAML:

```
<mui:ModernButton Margin="0,50"
              Content="This is the button"
              Background="#FF68217A"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              Foreground="Black" />
```

Comment: Look at the base control.  They hard code some properties sometimes.

Comment: The base control is System.Windows.Controls.Button. It easily responds to a change to Background. Thank you for your response, anyway.